Python Queue order
I was playing with a python queue problem and got it to work with the expected output (see bottom of post) ... when I tried to reverse the order of BOTH the insert and the pop (to see if this had the same output), the output seemed to go out of order.
class QueueError(IndexError):  # Choose base class for the new exception.

    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue = []


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__queue = []

    def put(self, elem):
        self.__queue.insert(-1, elem)

    def get(self):
        elem = self.__queue[0]
        del self.__queue[0]
        return elem


que = Queue()
que.put(1)
que.put("dog")
que.put(False)

try:
    for i in range(4):
        print(que.get())
except:
    print("Queue error")

this outputs: dog, False, 1 then Queue Error
What I don't get is why they are out of order (I would expect either "1, dog, False, [FIFO] + Queue Error"  OR "False, dog, 1, [LIFO] + Queue Error")  - I can't for the life of me work out why dog ends up at the beginning.
For completeness the original code in class Queue (before I experimented) was:
def put(self, elem):
    self.__queue.insert(-1, elem)

def get(self):
    elem = self.__queue[0]
    del self.__queue[0]
    return elem

which returned
1
dog
False
Queue error

I'm just starting with Classes/Queues so this may be (/probably is) an obvious logic error by me but I hate to just shrug and leave an anomaly that I don't understand.
Any comments appreciated

What's the purpose of QueueError? You never instantiate it.

Try creating a list at the REPL and run list.insert(-1, elem) a few times. Does it do what you expect? It looks like what you actually want is either list.insert(0, elem) or list.append(elem).

You may also be interested in What is wrong with using a bare 'except'? and Implementing an efficient queue in Python

insert(-1, x) does not insert x at the front of the list, but just before the last element of the list. (For empty and singleton lists, the result is equivalent.)

Where is put() supposed to insert the new element? To insert at the beginning, use .insert(0, elem). To add at the end use .append(elem).

The Queue error is from the original example code I had to add to ... basically it gets called when the loop tries to print an element that isn't there (3 elements, loop runs 4 times) ... I think they were just continuing the example of the 'try/except'.  It was their code that used 'except' bare - I know its not the way its meant to be done.

#Barmar ... I think that might be my misunderstanding (I'm maybe getting confused between c and Python).  I thought that -1 dropped it in at last index - I will redo with append and check.  Basically i was just trying to reverse both the push and pop to check I got the same result but ran out of knowledge :-)

#Brian61354270 Thanks - I'm ok with the bare except (it was the examples own coding) but the second link looks interesting.  Will definitely work though that, thanks.
